# Printing sorted files in Mac OS X (wrong order)

Tags: macos, printing, printer

I have many (about 100) files 1.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf... In Finder I sort them by name and sent to print, but they are not printing on the sort order (always 2.pdf -> 1.pdf -> 3.pdf or something like that). I tried create a program in  Automator where you select the files, they are sorted and sent to the printer, but again they are printed out of order.

This is a problem in the OS X or the printer (HP 1102w)?

Please help me, sorry for my english )

Comment: did you try adding pauses in automator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy or drag the files you have ordered directly into the print queue:

- Open System Preferences.
- Select Print & Scan. Select the printer that you want to use.
- Click on the button "Open Print Queue ..." on
  the right hand side.
- Now drag or copy/paste the list of files you want to
  print into the Print Queue window.